# Angular SEO (HTML snapshots and sitemap)

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, single-page-application, sitemap, snapshot

I've built a web application while learning Angular - http://magicspoiler.io

At the moment, I am using grunt-html-snapshots to create the snapshots to make the website crawlable by the search engines. Everything seems to work fine, but I have some questions.

1. My application has a lot of views (pages). Is there any easy way to create mass snapshots? Now, I have to write links to every page in the task config.
2. Is there any solution for creating the sitemap for SPAs?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is an instruction how can you make Angular site indexed and also how to create sitemap:
http://www.yearofmoo.com/2012/11/angularjs-and-seo.html

Within your website, use the hashbang or HTML5 URLS to point to the content--Google and Bing are smart enough to figure out that they're AJAX-generated pages.

Here is an example of a sitemap.xml entry for a AJAX webpage.

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  ...
  <url>
    <loc>http://www.yourwebsite.com/#!/home</loc>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <priority>1.0</priority>
  </url>
  ...
</urlset>
```

Comment: @blah Couple of points bc I'm also interested in this question: 1. That article only scratches the surface really. I think the question really talks about a large amount of static or large/dynamic content. How do you automate & keep synchronized, is there a resource that shows how to make it easier to 'feed' the snapshot script & generate a dynamic site map. 2. Do you need to use #! in the site map especially if using the newer `<meta name="fragment" content="!">`  in the article.  See [this](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification#hyperlinks-and-sitemap)